# split python source code into multiple files?

Tags: python

I have a code that I wish to split apart into multiple files. In matlab one can simply call a `.m` file, and as long as it is not defined as anything in particular it will just run as if it were part of the called code. Example (edited):
**test.m** (matlab)

```
function [] = test()
    ... some code using variables ...
    test2
```

**test2.m** (matlab)

```
... some more code using same variables ...
```

Calling `test` runs the code in test as well as the code in test2.

Is there a similar way for python, to put `... some more code ...`, into an external file, that will simply be read as if it is in the file that it is called from?

Comment: Yes there is, you can split your files in different modules and import what you need.
http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: Read your favorite Python tutorial and learn about modules

Comment: from python1_file import *

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I am researching module usage in python just now and thought I would answer the question Markus asks in the comments above ("How to import variables when they are embedded in modules?") from two perspectives:

1. variable/function, and
2. class property/method.

Here is how I would rewrite the main program f1.py to demonstrate variable reuse for Markus:

```
import f2
myStorage = f2.useMyVars(0) # initialze class and properties
for i in range(0,10):
    print "Hello, "
    f2.print_world()
    myStorage.setMyVar(i)
    f2.inc_gMyVar()
print "Display class property myVar:", myStorage.getMyVar()
print "Display global variable gMyVar:", f2.get_gMyVar()
```

Here is how I would rewrite the reusable module f2.py:

```
# Module: f2.py
# Example 1: functions to store and retrieve global variables
gMyVar = 0
def print_world():
    print "World!"
def get_gMyVar():
    return gMyVar # no need for global statement 
def inc_gMyVar():
    global gMyVar
    gMyVar += 1  

# Example 2: class methods to store and retrieve properties
class useMyVars(object):
    def __init__(self, myVar):
        self.myVar = myVar
    def getMyVar(self):
        return self.myVar
    def setMyVar(self, myVar):
        self.myVar = myVar
    def print_helloWorld(self):
        print "Hello, World!"
```

When f1.py is executed here is what the output would look like:

```
%run "f1.py"
Hello, 
World!
Hello, 
World!
Hello, 
World!
Hello, 
World!
Hello, 
World!
Hello, 
World!
Hello, 
World!
Hello, 
World!
Hello, 
World!
Hello, 
World!
Display class property myVar: 9
Display global variable gMyVar: 10
```

I think the point to Markus would be:

- To reuse a module's code more than once, put your module's code into
  functions or classes,
- To reuse variables stored as properties in modules, initialize
  properties within a class and add "getter" and "setter" methods so
  variables do not have to be copied into the main program,
- To reuse variables stored in modules, initialize the variables and use
  getter and setter functions. The setter functions would declare the
  variables as global.

Answer (score 89):

Sure!

```
#file  -- test.py --
myvar = 42
def test_func():
    print("Hello!")
```

Now, this file ("test.py") is in python terminology a "module".  We can import it (as long as it can be found in our `PYTHONPATH`) Note that the current directory is always in `PYTHONPATH`, so if `use_test` is being run from the same directory where `test.py` lives, you're all set:

```
#file -- use_test.py --
import test
test.test_func()  #prints "Hello!"
print (test.myvar)  #prints 42

from test import test_func #Only import the function directly into current namespace
test_func() #prints "Hello"
print (myvar)     #Exception (NameError)

from test import *
test_func() #prints "Hello"
print(myvar)      #prints 42
```

There's a lot more you can do than just that through the use of special `__init__.py` files which allow you to treat multiple files as a single module), but this answers your question and I suppose we'll leave the rest for another time.

Comment: Well, maybe my example is not so good. I wish to be able to call my extra code, with all my variables. Importing the module doesn't help me much as I would need to transfer the variables, no?

Comment: Variables can be imported as well, although it's not very common and you typically don't want to do that ... (see my update)

Comment: Hmm... far easier than I would have guessed!

Answer (score 24):

Python has importing and namespacing, which are good. In Python you can import into the current namespace, like:

```
>>> from test import disp
>>> disp('World!')
```

Or with a namespace:

```
>>> import test
>>> test.disp('World!')
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do the same in python by simply importing the second file, code at the top level will run when imported. I'd suggest this is messy at best, and not a good programming practice. You would be better off organizing your code into [modules](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html)

Example:

F1.py:

```
print "Hello, "
import f2
```

F2.py:

```
print "World!"
```

When run:

```
python ./f1.py
Hello, 
World!
```

Edit to clarify: The part I was suggesting was "messy" is using the `import` statement only for the side effect of generating output, not the creation of separate source files.

Comment: if I stick the `import f2` in a loop, it only writes `World!` once. Can I change it somehow?

Comment: I would put the `print` statement (in f2.py) in a function, import the file only once and call your new function in the loop.

Comment: But that's where I run into trouble calling actual code with variables needed in the main code and "sub-codes"

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing incorrect about the answers added so far, but they will only take you so far.

You may find yourself in the same situation as I did recently if your project begins to scale up.

## What is the limitation of modules?

Consider a project structure consisting of a "main script" and some library code which is organized into 1 or more modules.

What is the limitation of this? What happens if you want to have more than one binary?

**Asside:** Python does not have binaries as such. But you can have multiple scripts each with their own entry point. (A `def main()` function analagous to `int main()` in C, and similar `main` functions in other languages.) You may at some point find yourself wanting to write a project which consists of 1 or more libraries which are shared by multiple Python "binaries" (scripts). This is exactly analagous to the kind of project structure you might write in other languages including C, C++, Rust, Java, C#, and many others.

Back to the point: Using only the modules approach described above you are limited, and will be forced down a route of putting all library code in the same directory as a collection of things which are meant to be used like executables.

This is obviously not great.

## A possible solution using Virtual Environments, a build backend like setuptools, and a `pyproject.toml` file:

In summary, do the following things:

- create a Virtual Environment with `python3 -m venv .venv`
- activate it (enable the venv) `source .venv/bin/activate`

*Asside: I like to create a symlink to `.venv/bin/activate` so I can simply run `. activate` from the project root to activate my venvs.*

- install any libraries you need with `pip3 install ...`
- create a folder for your "binaries" called `bin`, put your "executable" Python scripts here
- create a folder called `src` for your library code
- for each library **module** create a directory under `src`
- add an `__init__.py` file to each library module
- add your module code for each library module
- create `pyproject.toml` in the project root (see below)
- "build" your libraries, and "install" them `pip3 install -e .` from the project root

What does all of this do?

What you are effectively doing here is moving module code out of one directory, where the python interpreter can find it, into another where it cannot. That doesn't seem to make a lot of sense, except to say the project directory structure is now improved. You should have some minimal "executable" python scripts in a `bin` directory and everything else logically organized under a `src` directory.

In order for the Python interpreter to find it, what you are doing here is "installing" your library code into the active Virtual Environment using `pip3`. In order to install it, you first need to build it with `setuptools`. When you build it and install it you use the `-e` flag. This installs it using symlinks instead of the usual way, which means if you modify your code, you can use the modifications immediatly without having to run the install step again.

Hopefully that all makes sense, I only recently learned about this, so this is my best attempt to provide a straightforward explanation.

## Example `toml` file

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "my_project_name"
version = "1.0.0"
description = "My Project Description"

[tools.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src"]
```