# Accessing another code in a different code Python

Tags: python, import

I was wondering on how I would access another python code within my existing code? Lets say the code I want to bring over is: code1.py and the code I am working with is code2.py
my idea on how to do this is:

```
import code1
```

At the very start of my code. Am I correct or is there another way of doing this?
Thanks!

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [split python source code into multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12412595/split-python-source-code-into-multiple-files)

Comment: Sure, but make sure code1 is in a function or the file will run by it's self.

Comment: Hello gdm, before submitting a question, please be sure to read StackOverflow's [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help other people offer a solution. In the case of this question it would have been nice to supply your current `code1.py` and `code2.py` files, what you tried to do and why it didn't work. Cheers mate!

Answer (score 1):

You can acces those functions with:
`code1.function(arg)`, where `code1` is your code1.py and `function` is a `function` (`def function(argument):`) from this file.

More on that [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)