# How can I link multiple files on python, it is very annoying while writing a very long codes

Tags: python-3.x

I’m new to python, I’m writing a code which requires multiple files because the code is getting bigger and bigger and it’s hard for me to figure out errors, someone should help

Comment: This is a duplicate question. Your answer is here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12412595/split-python-source-code-into-multiple-files)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [split python source code into multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12412595/split-python-source-code-into-multiple-files)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a Python file with a number of functions in it and call functions from other scripts. For example, you could name the file myfunctions.py and it could contain a function called function_one. If it is saved in the same directory as the Python script you are running, you can run it by

```
import myfunctions

myfunctions.function_one()
```